# Newbie Questions

Tags: discussion, tagging

Over the years (2 years, actually), I have seen many posts where the asker introduces himself/herself as a newbie. Some questions are blantantly easily, others more profound.

In either case, here is my question: **Should there be a [newbie](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newbie) tag attached to such questions ?** I figured since a [homework](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag exists, a [newbie](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newbie) may not be a bad thing. That way, DBA.SE can track that demographic.

Any thoughts on this ???

Comment: You can track the demographic by the down/close votes.

Comment: This kind of information is already tracked in the database implicitly. It's pretty easy to figure out if a question or answer is the user's first. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/38113/most-popular-tags-for-a-users-first-posts

Comment: Now you remembered me that I have to remove the homework tag from those questions...

Comment: This would qualify as a **meta tag**, which are explicitly discouraged on the network: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, I think this is quite similar to:

[Should there be a tag for classroom help?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/976/should-there-be-a-tag-for-classroom-help)

(Note that while the homework tag exists, it is only because it is very infrequently used and the moderators here have not bothered to abolish it - it has certainly been vanquished on SO.)

Just because the OP is a newbie does not mean that the answer should be any different; after all, the answer isn't just for the OP, and it may be useful to the OP a year from now when they're no longer as much of a newbie, never mind all the non-newbies that might benefit from the answer in the meantime.

So I don't believe such a tag will be beneficial in any way.